# PHP Fibonacci Sequence

Tags: php, for-loop

This php method is suppose to print the Fibonacci sequence up to a specified value using a for loop. I am unsure why it does not work?

```
<?php
function fib ($n) { // a function called fib, declaire variable n (the sequence number)
    for ($n=0;$n<30;$n++) {
        if ($n < 3) { return $n; } // if n is smaller than 3 return n (1 or 2)
        else { return fib ($n - 1) + fib ($n - 2); } 
    /* if the number is 3 or above do 2 sums (n-1) and (n-2)
    and then add the 2 sums together (n-1)+(n-2)
    Example Fibonacci number 4
    (4-1)+(4-2) = 5
    3 + 2 = 5
    */
}
print $n;
?>
```

Comment: Well, you're not going to print 1 twice are you..? Why do you have a special case? The point of a sequence is that there is not special case...

Comment: Is there a typo error or you just don't even call this function?

Comment: There may just be an issue with the loop but I don't really understand? I see a problem now though as it will only ever print one number?

Comment: My bad, is it a stupid question to ask whether you can call a method inside a method?

Comment: @Jesse Yes you can. An example where you will commonly see it is in ID generating functions where you want to generate an id, check that its not being used and if it is call the function again from within itself.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There is actually a way to calculate a Fibonacci number without iteration by using rounding:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Computation_by_rounding

```
function getFib($n)
{
    return round(pow((sqrt(5)+1)/2, $n) / sqrt(5));
}
```

Comment: As of PHP 5.6, you can use the [exponentiation operator (`**`)](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php): `round(((5 ** .5 + 1) / 2) ** $n / 5 ** .5)`.

Comment: Let me put some optimisations to solution above: instead of using the whole expression: `((5 ** .5 + 1) / 2)`, it is a golden ratio actually - using `1.618` will be enough and instead of using `5 ** .5` which is just `2.236` constant, thus we have `round(1.618 ** $n / 2.236)`. Another note - with round you are able to calculate around first 70 sequential numbers, >70 (depends on 32/64 arch) the number will be translated to double with scientific notation, but u can use `number_format/sprintf`

Answer (score 9):

Simple function of fibonacci

```
function fibonacci($n,$first = 0,$second = 1)
{
    $fib = [$first,$second];
    for($i=1;$i<$n;$i++)
    {
        $fib[] = $fib[$i]+$fib[$i-1];
    }
    return $fib;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r(fibonacci(50));
```

Comment: Only thing I dont like about this is adding $first and $second as parameter even if they are defaulted.. shows bad code and fibonacci is most likely a coding test, so thats a minus.

Answer (score 7):

In this example, I am using a for loop and limiting the length to 10:

```
$x = 0;    
$y = 1; 

for($i=0;$i<=10;$i++)    
{    
    $z = $x + $y;    
    echo $z."<br />";         
    $x=$y;       
    $y=$z;     
}
```

**Output:**
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
89
144

Comment: Nice simple approach. A "proper" Fibonacci sequence includes two 1s at the beginning, so I'd suggest echoing `$y` before entering the `for` loop.

Comment: You should echo $x and $y i.e `0 1` before for loop.

Answer (score 4):

you have 2 sulutions

> using for loop

```
function fib($n) {
    $fib_array = [0, 1];
    for ($i = 2; $i < $n; $i++) {
        $fib_array[$i] = $fib_array[$i - 1] + $fib_array[$i - 2];
    }
    return $fib_array;
}

print_r(fib(6));
```

> recursive functions

```
function rec_fib($x) {
    if ($n < 2) {
        return $n;
    }
    return fib($n - 1) + fib($n - 2);
}

print_r(rec_fib(6));
```

Answer (score 3):

Your basic understanding of how the language works seems wrong. You're defining a function but never calling it. You are giving a parameter that you then immediately overwrite.

Try this:

```
$fib = [1,0];
for($i=0; $i<30; $i++) {
    $next = array_sum($fib);
    array_shift($fib);
    array_push($fib,$next);
    echo $next.", ";
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to call the method each time the for loop loops in order to display each of the numbers in the sequence?

Comment: What's what the `echo` line does.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I'm no php guy, but I believe the `echo` is more of like `console.log(..)` in javascript or `print` in python

Answer (score 3):

I know I am 1 year late, but here is my contribution.
There are 2 possible solutions:

```
function fib1($n)
{
    return $n < 3 ? 1 : fib1($n - 1) + fib1($n - 2);
}
function fib2($n, $c = 2, $n2 = 0, $n1 = 1)
{
    return $c < $n ? fib2($n, $c + 1, $n1, $n1 + $n2) : $n1 + $n2;
}
```

The first one is more elegant and calculates the result same way as it is defined mathematically. The problem is it is very expensive for big $n.

The second one is much faster, but you have to make sure user sets only the first parameter.

Execution time:

> $n = 20, fib1 = 0.092s, fib2 = 0.001s
>
> $n = 30, fib1 = 12.2827s, fib2 = 0.001s
>
> $n = 40, fib1 = >500s fib2 = 0.001s

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting the `$n` you get as function argument when you let `$n` to be the loop counter.

Get rid of the `for`-statement, leave just the body of it.

Answer (score 2):

```
    function fibonacci( $n ) {
if (( $n == 0 ) || ( $n == 1 )) {
     return $n;
}
return fibonacci( $n-2 ) + fibonacci( $n-1 );}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function fib($m){
    $j=0;$k=1;
    for($i=0;$i<=$m;$i++){
          $l=$k;
          $k=$j+$k;
          $j=$l;
      }
   return $k;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the method used by me:

```
function fibonacci_series($n) {
  $f1 = -1;
  $f2 = 1;

  for ($i = 1; $i <= $n; $i++) {
    $f = $f1 + $f2;
    $f1 = $f2;
    $f2 = $f;
    echo "$f<br />"; 
  }
 }

echo fibonacci_series(5);
```

For explanation visit [here](http://www.phponwebsites.com/2015/06/php-fibonacci-series-of-given-number.html)

Answer (score 1):

A more readable, non-recursive approach:

```php
function fibonacciSequence($max = 13) {
    if($max < 1)
        return [];

    $sequence = [];

    $older = 0;
    $newer = 1;

    do {
        $number = $newer + $older;
        $sequence[] =  $number;

        $older = $newer;
        $newer = $number;
    } while($number < $max);

    return $sequence;
}
```

Comment: You don't see do/while very often in PHP and this is exactly an example of where to use it, so +1.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getFib($n, $nN, $ct = 0, $max = 100)
 {
     $ct++;
     echo "$nN \n";
     ($ct < $max) ? getFib($nN, $n+$nN, $ct) : die();

 }

 echo 0;
 getFib(0, 1);
```

Recursive Fib

Answer (score 1):

Fibonacci Series looks like:

0 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 5 , 8 , 13 , 21 , 34 ,

```
function fabnacaiiSeries($num){
    $first=0;$second=1;
    for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++){
        if($i<=1){
            $next=$i;
        }  else  {
            $next=$first+$second;
            $first=$second;
            $second=$next;
        }

        echo  $next." , ";
    }   
}

fabnacaiiSeries(10);
```

[View more detail](http://solvemyquest.com/print-fibonacci-series-in-php/)

Answer (score 1):

This is inefficient fib ($n - 1) + fib ($n - 2); here are my solutions with recursion and without. I'm not using accumulated dictionaries like $fib[1..N] = [] but I calculate step sum and pass it to next iteration or recursion call.

```
// with recursion 
function fib($n, $a = 0, $b = 1) {
    if ($n < 1) {
        return $a;
    }        

    return fib($n - 1, $b, $a + $b);
}


// with simple loop
function fib($N) {
    $a = 0;
    $b = 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $N; $i++) {
        $t = $a + $b;
        $a = $b;
        $b = $t;
    }
    return $a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Use this
 function printFibonacci($n)
 {

  $first = 0;
  $second = 1;

  echo "Fibonacci Series n => ";

  echo $first.' '.$second.' ';

  for($counter = 2; $counter < $n; $counter++){

    $third = $first + $second;

    echo $third.' ';

    $first = $second;
    $second = $third;

    }
}

/* Function call to print Fibonacci series upto 10 numbers. */

printFibonacci(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it recursively

```
function fib($n, $first, $second) {
    if( $n > 0 ) {
         $sum = $first + $second;
         $first = $second;
         $second = $sum;
         print $sum;
         fib($n-1, $first, $second);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = 0;
$x = 0;
$y = 1;

echo $x."<br />";
echo $y."<br />";

while($count < 10) {
    $z = $x + $y;
    echo $z."<br />";
    $x = $y;
    $y = $z;
    $count ++;
}
```

Refer: http://blog.innovsystems.com/php/fibonacci-series-program-php

Comment: I believe your code is helpful to the person asking the question, but it doesn't really answer his question. The code also doesn't implement the function he is looking for. A bit more explanation would probably help him.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Working PHP code for fibonacci sequence

```
$prev = 0;
$curr = 1;
$fib = 0;
for($i=0;$i<=20;$i++){
    echo $fib . ",";               
    $prev = $curr;
    $curr = $fib;
    $fib = $prev + $curr; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is as fast and as simple as I could make it

```
function fibonacci($n, $rec = 0) {
    echo "$n\t";
    fibonacci($n + $rec, $n);
}
echo fibonacci(1);
```

Include `header('Content-Type: text/plain');` to see the \t tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question recently and found your question. You were half-way there then I modified your code to working version.

```
<?php

function fib ($n) { // a function called fib, declaire variable n (the sequence number)
    if($n==0) return 0;
    if ($n < 3) { return 1; } // if n is smaller than 3 return n (1 or 2)
    else { return fib ($n - 1) + fib ($n - 2); }
    /* if the number is 3 or above do 2 sums (n-1) and (n-2)
    and then add the 2 sums together (n-1)+(n-2)
    Example Fibonacci number 4
    (4-1)+(4-2) = 5
    3 + 2 = 5
    */

}

        echo fib(50);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    $b=1; $limit=500;
    for($a=$b++;$a<$limit;$b+=$a=$b-$a)    
    {    
       echo"$a<br>"; 
      }   
   ?>
```

*EDIT: Let's start with `$b=1; $a=$b+$a` and `$b=1 =>` at the begining we can say `$a=$b++;` then we put a limit `$a<$limit;` now hardest part `$b+=$a=$b-$a` means `$b=$b+$a;` and `$a=$b-$a;`
lets operate this code together and have fun

step 1: a--->1....b--->2 // b was =1 a=1=> b=b+a=1+1=2

step 2: a--->1....b--->3 // b was 2 a=b-a=2-1=1 => b=b+a=2+1=3

step 3: a--->2....b--->5// b was 3 a=b-a=3-1=2 =>b=b+a=3+2=5

> output: 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Ok. I added some explanation @TobySpeight

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://www.sitesbay.com/php-program/php-fibonacci-series-program-in-php) did it well. You may check it for a references. Thanks!

```
<?php

function printFibonacci($n)
{

  $first = 0;
  $second = 1;

  echo "Fibonacci Series \n";

  echo $first.' '.$second.' ';

  for($i = 2; $i < $n; $i++){

    $third = $first + $second;

    echo $third.' ';

    $first = $second;
    $second = $third;

  }
}

/* Function call to print Fibonacci series upto 6 numbers. */

printFibonacci(6);

?>
```

Or

```
<?php

define('NUM',11);
$a = 0;
$b = 1;

echo "$a $b "; // 0 1

for($i=1   ; $i<= NUM-2 ;  $a=$b, $b=$c, $i++ ) 
{
  echo $c = $a+$b;
  echo " ";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$num = array(0, 1);

for ($i=0; $i<=10; $i++) 
{
   $new_num = $num[$i-1] + $num[$i-2];
   array_push($num, $new_num);
}

echo implode(', ',$num);
?>
```

Comment: While answers are always appreciated, this question was asked 4 **years** ago, and already had an accepted solution. Please try to avoid 'bumping' questions to the top by providing answers to them, unless the question was not already marked as resolved, or you found a new and improved solution to the problem. Also remember to provide some [**context surrounding your code**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762) to help explain it. Check out the documentation on [**writing great answers**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some tips on how to make your answers count :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    function generateFibonacci($n, $previous = 0, $current = 1) {
        echo $previous == 0 ? $previous.'<br />'.$current.'<br />' : $current . '<br />';

        return $n == 1 ? null : generateFibonacci($n - 1, $current, $previous + $current);
    }

    generateFibonacci(20);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  class fibonacci
   {

   public $x = 0;
   public $y = 1;

   public function fibonacci() {
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) {
     $z = $this->x + $this->y;
     echo $z;
     echo "<br>";
     $this->x = $this->y;
     $this->y = $z;
    }

   }

   }

  $objfib = new fibonacci();
///Output
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
89
144
```

Answer (score 0):

Fibonaccies are so easy to get by making a recursion

```
function printFibo($prev, $next) {
   if($prev > 10000000000000) return;
   $num = $prev + $next;

   echo "$num<br>";
   printFibo($next, $num); 
}

printFibo(0, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was asked to write a fibonacci function the other day in an interview.  I considered a recursion, yet at the time I thought it would be inefficient.

I ended up writing mine like this:

```
function fib ($num) {
    $count = 0;
    $current = 0;
    $one_back = 0;
    $two_back = 0;

    while ($count <= $num) {    
        $current = $one_back + $two_back;
        $two_back = $two_back ? $one_back : 1;
        $one_back = $current;
        $count++;
    }

    return $current;
}
```

They only wanted the final answer though obviously it could be easily modified to push every iteration onto an array.

Later, I tested mine against a recursive version...mine is faster.

If $num is > 1476 it returns INF, so I'm assuming that's where you hit the max integer value of php.

For fun, pass 1476 into a recursive fibonacci function, and watch your computer melt :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function fibonacciSequence($pos){

    $fibarray = array(0, 1);

   for ( $i=2; $i<=$pos; ++$i ) {
       $fibarray[$i] = $fibarray[$i-1] + $fibarray[$i-2];
   }

   return $fibarray;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r(fibonacciSequence(5));
echo "<pre>";
```

Comment: Please add context why this works and is better than other posted answers on SO. (End of Low-Quality Review).

Answer (score 0):

```
$first=0;
$second=1;
$nex=0;
$num=10;
for($c=0;$c<$num;$c++)
{
    if($c<=1)
    {
       $next=$c; 
    }
    else
    {
    $next=$first+$second;
    $first=$second;
    $second=$next;    
    }
    echo $next;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Although your answer may be correct, you have not given any context to your answer. There is already an accepted answer to this question as well, and because this question is in excess of 6 years old, if your answer does not contribute a better answer, maybe it is better not to post one.

Answer (score 0):

Fibonacci Series looks like:
1 , 2 , 3 , 5 , 8 , 13 , 21 , 34 , 55 , 89 ,144
Means if you add the previous two values and output show is the next value.

1+2 = 3
3+5 = 8
Like this
How to achieve this type of output in PHP

```
<?php
$num1 = 0 ; 
$num2 = 1 ; 

for ($i=0; $i<=10 ; $i++) { 
    # Foboniici
    $result = $num1 + $num2 ; 
    $num1 = $num2 ; 
    $num2 = $result ; 
    echo $result ; 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```
        function fibonacci($length)
    {
        $result = [];
    
        function start($index, $a = 0, $b = 1)
        {
            if ($index === 0) {
                return $a;
            }
    
            if ($index === 1) {
                return $b;
            }
    
            return start( $index- 1, $b, $a + $b);
        }
    
        for ($i = 0; $i <= $length; $i++) {
            $result[$i] = start($i);
        }
    
        return $result;
    }

var_dump(fibonacci(20));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the theory of the following link, I came up with this.

```php
<?php
/**
 * 
 * Xn = Xn−1 + Xn−2
 * 
 */
function theFibonacci($num){
    if($num < 2){
        echo $num;
    }
    
    $result = [0, 1];
    for($x=2;$x<=$num;$x++){
        $X1 = $result[$x-1]; // Xn−1
        $X2 = $result[$x-2]; // Xn−2
        $Xn = $X1 + $X2; // Xn = Xn−1 + Xn−2
        
        $result[$x] = $Xn;

    }
    
   echo $result[$num];
}

theFibonacci(14);
```

First, if the number is less than two, return the same number. If the number is equal or greater than two, use the initial values to get the next Fibonacci value.

Answer (score -1):

Try this. Optimized function

```
function fib($n, $all=0){
f[0] = 1;
f[1] = 1;
for($i = 2; $i<= $n; $i++) f[$i] = f[$i-1]+f[$i-2];
if($all) return $f;
return $f[$n];
}

print fib(5);
var_dump(fib(5, 1));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    <?php
echo"Ashutosh Verma Branch_IT_9889313834";
echo"<br />";
echo "Fibonacci Series Up to 10th term is:-"."<br />";
$fibonacci=0;
$a=0;
$b=1;
echo $a.",";
echo $b.",";
while($fibonacci<20)
{
$c=$a+$b;
echo $c.",";
$a=$b;
$b=$c;
$fibonacci=$fibonacci + 1;
}
?>
------------------------------------------OUTPUT-------------------------------------
Ashutosh Verma Branch_IT_9889313834
Fibonacci Series Up to 10th term is:-
0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233,377,610,987,1597,2584,4181,6765,10946,
```

Answer (score -1):

Just adding my two cents, using recursion:

```
<?php

function fibonacci($previous = 0, $actual = 0)
{
    #setting a hard limit
    if ($previous > 100) {
        return;
    }

    $result = $previous + $actual; 

    echo $actual."\n";
    fibonacci($actual, $result?:1);
}

fibonacci();
```

Comment: This is the 39th answer to this question. It is basically the same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/51004919/2209007 from 2018 and to some extend https://stackoverflow.com/a/29224134/2209007 from 2015 (although that one runs for an infinite time). Please make sure that the answer you want to give has not already been given, even if (or rather: especially if) a question has as many answers as this one.

Answer (score -2):

Mine is a simple method to get the fibonacii series, check this out:

```
function fibo() {
    $a = 0;
    $b = 1;

    echo $a;
    for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) { 
        echo ' '.$b.' ';
        $sum = $a + $b;
        $a = $b;
        $b = $sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: how does it differ from [this already posted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42069091/1575188) ?