# Fibonacci Sequence - PHP shortest code possible

Tags: php

I have spent some time trying to execute the Fibonacci sequence to 500 numbers and output to screen in the shortest amount of code possible. This was a learning exercise for me.

I have condensed it from 21 lines down to 12, this is the shortest code I can write that makes this work.. Can anyone show me how I could have made the code even shorter?

I have looked on google for PHP loops, and the while loop seemed to work best.
Are there any other math tricks in PHP I can use to condense this even more?

Normally when I ask a question, I like to show what research I have done into the problem, but since I don't know any keywords to look up for better math or loops, I am not sure what to search..

Code:

```
$counter = 0;
$first = 1;
$second = 1;
echo $first."<br/>";
echo $second."<br/>";
while ($counter < 500) {
  $next = $first + $second;
  echo $next."<br/>";
  $counter++;
  $second=$first;
  $first=$next;
}
```

Comment: This question belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Fibonacci Sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15600041/php-fibonacci-sequence)

Comment: Could belong on http://codegolf.stackexchange.com

Comment: This likely belongs on http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ and I would actually be surprised if it doesn't already exist there in some format.

Comment: Also, if your goal is to make the shortest possible code, you can combine many of the lines. You don't need two echo statements, the `while` loop could be a `for` loop which could remove about 5 lines.

Comment: Didnt know of codereview.. Thank you! Also, combination of echo "1<br/>1<br/>"; is a good suggestion.. The goal is only to output to screen correctly.. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you Clement.. I found syntax on that link I was not aware of.. That is EXACTLY what I was looking for:  array_sum, array_shif, array_push!

Comment: Is there a practical use for generating Fibonacci sequences?  I haven't done this since school so I feel like you just got homework help, haha.  But I might just be in the wrong field?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The research for the shortest code is called "code golf" and there is a [whole stack exchange site](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com) devoted to it.

In particular, your question is answered [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1647/2776).

The code is:

```
<?for($a=$b++;;$b+=$a=$b-$a){echo$a;}
```

this works by:

- removing whitespaces (which are ignored anyway) (cosmetic)
- giving variables meaningless names (doesn't affect the output)(cosmetic)
- abusing various language features like implicit initialization to zero and multiple assignments
- the multiple assignment trick lets you use two variables instead of three (no need for the "current number") exploiting the order of the assignment